# Set and retain column widths of Split Form datasheet columns in MS-Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm using a `Split Form` in Access 2012. Basic datasheet view on top with individual record and form header in bottom pane.

I'm trying to figure if there's a way to keep my column widths to manually sized widths - and ideally, set column widths to BestFit via VBA code when the Form loads.

I have found [this one hack](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=207123) that remembers the column widths the next time you start.

> *I had the same problem. What worked for me (Access 2010 Split Form)
>   was to resize all the columns (by dragging the right edge of the
>   column header) the way I wanted, then right click any column header
>   and select "Hide Column." Hide any column, click "Ok" then right click
>   again on any column, choose "Unhide Column" and unhide the one you hid
>   in the first place. Click "Ok" and presto the form opens with the
>   resized column widths every time.*

But the problem happens again if I distribute the database.

If I could somehow reference the datasheet view columns object, I could probably apply the BestFit method

> **EDIT - UPDATE: I have tried using this function to no effect:**

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
   With ctl 
      Select Case .ControlType
         Case acTextBox
            Debug.Print .Name
            If Not .ColumnHidden Then
               .ColumnWidth = -2
            End If
      End Select
  End With
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

### Unfortunately, "Me.[Field1].ColumnWidth = -2" does not work for split view.

This bizarre series of steps appears to be the only way to save column widths in an MS Access (2007-2013) "split form":

1. In split view, set your columns widths on the datasheet side of the form. Double-click on the right edge of any column if you want to set it to the **current** *Best Fit* (unfortunately even "Best Fit" will be saved as a static width).
2. Highlight the columns with widths you want to save. If you are doing all of them, **do not use Select-All**; select the first column header, then shift-click on the last column header.
3. Right-click on the center of any highlighted column header, then click *Hide Fields*. All of your columns should disappear. Don't worry, this is supposed to happen.
4. Under the Home menu tab, click on *More > Unhide Fields*, and select all of the columns.
5. Hit *Save*, then go into Design view, and hit *Save* again. Your column widths will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried this method in your form? Where `-2` is best fit. Note: without the `[]` brackets it wont work.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.[Field1].ColumnWidth = -2
    Me.[Field2].ColumnWidth = -2
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried a variation to no effect - updated my question

Comment: In a split form? - or a datasheet form?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling this function which seems to work o a split form

```
Public Function AutofitDatasheetColumns()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls
        On Error Resume Next
        ctl.ColumnWidth = -2
    Next ctl
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).