# Set column width on dynamic datasheet sub-form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm working on a very small Access 2007 project after many years not using it. I have a form where you can select a number of items to display in the datasheet sub-form from a query and that's working fine. The problem I have is that as the datasheet columns are not predefined, I can't find a way to set the column widths.

Thoughts or solutions would be appreciated.

I do not believe the other solution suggested is relevant as it is not suited to a dynamic datasheet. The datasheet fields are generated from a query and the result is used to change the SourceObject. There can be any number of fields from 2 to 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set and retain column widths of Split Form datasheet columns in MS-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151663/set-and-retain-column-widths-of-split-form-datasheet-columns-in-ms-access)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate as this is not an option for a dynamically created datasheet.

Comment: Exactly how is the datasheet created dynamically? Is the subform container holding a form or table/query? Edit question to provide info.